# typeof call vs typeof expression

Tags: r

The R-lang states: "There are three types of objects that constitute the R language. They are calls, expressions, ..."

These are an expression and a call:

```
ex <- expression(max(1:3))
cl <- call("max", x = 1:3)
```

They are both language objects:

```
is.language(ex)
# [1] TRUE
is.language(cl)
# [1] TRUE
```

Expressions are of type *expression*

```
typeof(ex)
# [1] "expression"
```

I would have expected calls being of type *call* but they are of the more generic type *language*

```
typeof(cl)
# [1] "language"
```

Does anyone know if there any rational behind this? Am I missing something important?

Thanks in advance for any support

Answer (score 2):

`typeof` returns information about the storage mechanism. That's why `typeof( factor(letters) )` returns `integer`.

It's generally more informative to query an object with the `class` function rather than using `typeof`.

```
> class(cl)
[1] "call"
```

The `?typeof` help page also refers you to `?storage.mode` which has further details, even though `typeof` is the more "fundamental" function in the sense that `storage.mode` is defined using `typeof`:

```
> storage.mode(cl)
[1] "language"
```

The difference between R expressions and calls has occasionally tripped me up. The `bquote` function returns a `call`-object and not a "true" R expression. At one time that resulted in lattice plotting functions refusing to do plotmath evaluation on results from `bquote`, although I think that glitch has been fixed. You should also become familiar with the operation of substitute and the differences in how it parses it's arguments:

```
substitute( expression(max(1:3)), list(max=min))
#expression(.Primitive("min")(1:3))  # Success

substitute( call('max', x=1:3), list(max=min))
#call("max", x = 1:3)  #Failure
```